# How to create a database out of the Tezos node?

Tags: rpc, query, database, conseil

We want to build a Website that contains Live-Data from the Tezos-Node.

We have a node running, we have the RPCs, we have a mysql database and we want to use Postgres to query the database and "feed" the website with info.

We just don't know, how to "extract" the Data from the Tezos-Node into the Database.

An approach is Conseil from Cryptonomic.

https://github.com/Cryptonomic/Conseil

But they don't support the Voting/Ballot RPCs at the moment:

Answer (score 17):

You could modify Conseil in order to support the extraction of voting related info.

Another approach is to use the [tzscan codebase](https://gitlab.com/tzscan/tzscan), which also fills a database with information from the Tezos node.

Last but not least, you can use RPC calls to `/chains/main/blocks/head/context/raw/json/..` to explore the raw context for every block.