# Hwo do I get list of operations using RPC api?

Tags: transactions, rpc

What's the API to get list of transactions for a given `address`?

Answer (score 3):

There are no RPC for doing that. To get that kind of data you need to store and organize the blockchain in a relational database. See this question for more details on how this can be done: [How to create a database out of the Tezos node?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-to-create-a-database-out-of-the-tezos-node)